# XPath for an element when a related element contains a value?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<originDestinationDetails>
    <originDestination></originDestination>
    <itineraryInfo>
      <elementManagementItinerary>
        <reference>
          <qualifier>ST</qualifier>
          <number>1</number>
        </reference>
        <segmentName>RU</segmentName>
        <lineNumber>2</lineNumber>
      </elementManagementItinerary>
      <travelProduct>
        <product>
          <depDate>201116</depDate>
        </product>
        <boardpointDetail>
          <cityCode>CWB</cityCode>
        </boardpointDetail>
        <companyDetail>
          <identification>1A</identification>
        </companyDetail>
      </travelProduct>
      <itineraryMessageAction>
        <business>
          <function>32</function>
        </business>
      </itineraryMessageAction>
      <relatedProduct>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <status>HK</status>
      </relatedProduct>
      <itineraryFreetext>
        <freetextDetail>
          <subjectQualifier>3</subjectQualifier>
        </freetextDetail>
        <longFreetext>-CAR/HERTZ/PUP-20NOV-0700/RT-22NOV-1800/VT-ICAR/CF-125456/SI-NVS</longFreetext>
```

I want to return the `cityCode` from

`originDestinationDetails/itineraryInfo/travelProduct/boardpointDetail/cityCode`

But only where the `longFreetext` node contains `'CAR'`.

I've been at this for hours and have tried various different `'contains'`. Just cannot get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried predicates in xpath? http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: btw you may have accidentally cut out your XML. Cause your missing end tags. Here is where I tried validating your XML. http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html
http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/originDestinationDetails
    /itineraryInfo[contains(itineraryFreetext/longFreetext, 'CAR')]
    /travelProduct/boardpointDetail/cityCode
```

will select only those `cityCode` elements in `itineraryInfo` elements that have `longFreetext` whose string value contains the string `"CAR"`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much.